# Python equivalent to Matlab's set function

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, set

Is there an equivalent expression in Python for the Matlab function `set`? Here's the link: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/set.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very similar to the builtin `setattr`.

Use is basically:

```
setattr(myObject, "key", "value")
```

Or in the python docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr

Answer (score 2):

It's just `setp` in `matplotlib`.

Comment: It's often more convenient to use the `set` method of a matplotlib artist.  E.g. `ax.set(xlabel='This', ylabel='That', xlim=[1, 10])`. However, `plt.setp` will operate on sequences of artists, which can also be handy.

Comment: Cool! I'm trying to write a simulation and I guess `setp` would be more useful.